# Server application closes when receiving message

Tags: c#, sockets, asyncsocket

Well I'm making a Client-Server application and I can send messages to my client just fine but when I do it the other way around (Client to server) the server application just closes down, any help on how to fix this?

```
public void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
        try
        {
            SocketPacket socketData = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;

            int iRx = 0;
            iRx = socketData.m_currentSocket.EndReceive(asyn);
            char[] chars = new char[iRx + 1];
            System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
            int charLen = d.GetChars(socketData.dataBuffer,
                                     0, iRx, chars, 0);
            System.String szData = new System.String(chars);
            area1.AppendText(szData);


            WaitForData(socketData.m_currentSocket); // Continue the waiting for data on the Socket
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "1", "\nOnDataReceived: Socket has been closed\n");
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
        }
    }
```

After doing some breakpoints I realized it closes after reaching this part when it tries to append it on the textArea it closes without an error.

Any ideas on how to fix this? I guessing something to do with the threads but not sure why it just closes.

Comment: Also the data I'm getting from szData is "t/0" (when the word I send via the client is test). No errors, exceptions or anything but if I comment the area1.AppendText(szData); part it won't close anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does an exception happen when `AppendText` is called?  If yes, can you include the call stack?  Is szData valid data when AppendText is called?  Try putting a try/catch around the code to get the exception information:

```
try
{
    ... your code...
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ... examine 'e' in the debugger or dump it to a log file
}
```

One  thing that might be going wrong is that you are accessing a UI control from the non-UI thread, but it could be other things.  It's hard to tell from the code snippet you posted.

Updated:
If the exception was that the control is being invoked from the wrong thread, you can try adding a function like this, then calling that instead of accessing the control directly  (untested):

```
    private void AppendText(string text)
    {
        // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
        // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
        // If these threads are different, it returns true.
        if (this.area1.InvokeRequired)
        {   
            SetTextCallback d = new AppendTextCallback(AppendText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.area1.AppendText(text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sry I'll update the entire code for that section, I'm not getting any error so no exceptions either, but from what I can see the data I'm getting is strange I'm sending a simple word "test" but I receive "t/0"

Comment: Sounds like you are decoding the text incorrectly -- can you try a different decoder?  Also, you are saying that the process exits during the AppendText call but there is no exception?

Comment: I'll try a different decoder, and yeah that's where it happens if I comment that line the program wont close anymore.

Comment: I see your exception handling now -- are you only catching ObjectDisposedException & SocketException types?   Can you also add a catch-all "catch (Exception e)" to make sure some other type is not being thrown?

Comment: You were right, I get cross-thread exception, says: Control 'area1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: Ok then you need to do an invoke so the call is done on the right thread.   Here is a link on how to do this:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.80).aspx